I can ssh and access the webserver but ping fails
My knowledge about networking is basic.
I have several computers in a intranet. Let's call one of them the DB_Host.
I want to ping this computer.
So I do
ping DB_Host.intranet.com -c 1

When I do that from the same computer , the ping finishes with no problem.
However from my local PC, that I connect to the intranet through a VPN, when I do the ping I get
ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms. 

So, it seems there is a connection problem from my local_pc
I would like to know in simple terms what could be the factors that could impede me to access this DB_Host, and what can I do to overcome it.
As I said, I access the intranet without problem with the VPN. I also have access to http files hosted in DB_host (it is running a web server). I can also ssh it. The thing I can't it seems is ping.

"When I do that from the same computer , the ping finishes with no problem" – (1) Does DB_Host.intranet.com resolve to the expected address here and there? (2) What is the output of cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all on the system you want to ping? (3) A firewall on any end may block certain network packets. Check the firewalls.
